# What does this error say? Type 'ParsedQs' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

Hello my problem is I want to use the search query of mongoose. But I want to make a get request using a query. Why is that not possible? I do not understand this error. I am using version 5.10.0 of mongoose.
I don't want to do it as a post request and I would not like to use req.body. Can anyone help me?

here my code:

```
export const searching = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  Company.find({ $text: { $search: req.query } }).exec((err, docs) => {
    if (docs) {
      res.status(200).json(docs)
    } else {
      console.log(err)
    }
  })
}
```

my error message:

```
(property) $search: string
No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Type 'ParsedQs' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2769)
```

Answer (score 24):

`req.query` is an object containing request query

So if you send a request to the endpoint like this `/?foo=bar&a=123`

You can access the query value from

```js
req.query.foo // bar
req.query.a // 123
```

You are passing query object to the `$search`, meanwhile you are supposed to pass a string, so it should be

```js
Company.find({ $text: { $search: req.query.yourQueryKey as string } }).exec((err, docs) => {
```

---

Better solution is to type your `RequestHandler` function

```
import {RequestHandler} from "express";

type Params = {};
type ResBody = {};
type ReqBody = {};
type ReqQuery = {
    query: string;
}

export const searching: RequestHandler<Params, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery> = (req, res) => {
    const query = req.query.query; // string
}
```

Even better solution: type your `RequestHandler` function and use a validation library to validate the request query like [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) or [celebrate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/celebrate)

Comment: Yes but the problem is that even if I type req.query.foo or something like that I get the same error. 

This: 

`No overload matches this call.
 The last overload gave the following error.
 Type 'string | ParsedQs | string[] | ParsedQs[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Comment: Check my edit. You need to cast the type to string using `as`

Comment: Does this solution take into account that multiple equal query parameters in the URL query, for instance "http://demo.com/path?id=first&id=second", would result in req.query.id being an array of ParsedQs or strings, like ["first", "second"]?

Comment: Thank you @Owl for recommanding `celebrate` module in addition to `RequestHandler` function: it is a very powerful combo!

Answer (score 5):

You are passing req.query to your search and the default Typescript type for req.query is

```
Request<unknown, unknown, unknown, QueryString.ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>.query: QueryString.ParsedQs
```

and if you passed in req.query.searchText the type for that would be

```
string | QueryString.ParsedQs | string[] | QueryString.ParsedQs[] | undefined
```

The simple way is already answered here just do

```
export const searching = (req: Request, res: Response) => { 
const searchText = req.query. searchText as string
  Company.find({ $text: { $search: searchText } }).exec((err, docs) => {
    if (docs) {
      res.status(200).json(docs)
    } else {
      console.log(err)
    }
  })
}
```

That works but gets sloppy when you have a lot of variables from your query params. In express try out the  RequestHandler for your endpoints.

```
import { RequestHandler } from 'express'

interface QueryTypes {
  searchText: string
  moreSearchText: string
}
export const searching:RequestHandler<unknown, unknown, unknown, QueryTypes > = (req, res) => {
  Company.find({ $text: { $search: req.query } }).exec((err, docs) => {
    if (docs) {
      res.status(200).json(docs)
    } else {
      console.log(err)
    }
  })
}
```

You can see using the RequestHandler I can pass in a few unknown types and the fourth one I can pass in the query types. I can also remove the Request and Response types to just (req, res) because RequestHandler already types out the handler for us.

You're probably wondering what the 3 previous unknown are and that too in the typescript docs for RequestHandler. Here is the docs.

```
interface RequestHandler<P = core.ParamsDictionary, ResBody = any, ReqBody = any, ReqQuery = qs.ParsedQs, Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>>
```

Now using RequestHandler. I can type out parameters, body, reqbody or query. Use a combo or skip them using unknown like I did in my example.

This also has the added benefit of giving you type safety so

```
const test = req.query.test
```

would highlight a typescript error in vscode for me because 'test' is defined in my QueryTypes interface.

Comment: I found that interfaces make Express complain if I pass more than one middleware (because they don't have the same `RequestHandler` types). I didn't get the same error with `type` declarations.

Comment: for your middleware you can always reset the RequestHandler<any, any, any, any> or replace any with unknown.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea why this problem doesn't appear when you use `type` instead of `interface`?

Comment: when you use type it uses the type only within the current handler. It doesn't change the handler signature like the generic does.

Comment: where `QueryString` is coming from?

Comment: it's defined by express types

Answer (score 1):

`req.query` is *an object* that contains all of query parameters you specified in the query.

If your request looks like this

```
test.com/search/?s=something
```

`something` will be stored in `req.query.s`.

The second option is to use [named route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters).
So you can set do this:

Request URL

```
test.com/search/something
```

Route

```
app.get('/search/:search', (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.params.search); // "something". NB use req.params, not req.query
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Quick and dirty solution**

If your coming here from search, the answer can be quite a bit easier than the others suggested here depending on your use case and specific implementation.

Failure Example:

```js
const foo: string | null = req.query.bar || null 

// Type 'ParsedQs' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Success Example:

```js
const foo: string | null = <string>req.query.bar || null
// No Type errors
```

Are there risks with this type of inline type definition, yes. If you are certain your values will always be strings, and you're not wanting to dive through all of the Express type definitions and muck up your code with a ton of type definitions so you can simply work with a request variable that is a string and will be a string, then this is probably a good solution for ya.