# Typescript - How to parse query parameters into number value

Tags: typescript, express, type-conversion

I have a express API endpoint where I need to receive two numbers from the query parameters.

The problem is that I cannot convert them properly into number type constants.

I always get the following typescript error:
`Argument of type 'string | ParsedQs | string[] | ParsedQs[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

```
export const getRoutes = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const page:number = parseInt(req.query.page)
  const limit:number = parseInt(req.query.limit)
```

Comment: Just help typescript to understand it is a string: `parseInt(req.query.page as string)`. Even if it is not - you'll get a `NaN` (same as with non parsable string)

Comment: Also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63579867/what-does-this-error-say-type-parsedqs-is-not-assignable-to-type-string

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just mentioning what Aleksey L. said but putting it here so people can see the answer easily

```
export const getRoutes = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const page:number = parseInt(req.query.page as string)
  const limit:number = parseInt(req.query.limit as string)
}
```

That would help typescript interpret req.query.page as a string and then be able to parse it as an integer.